# drop-down list border

Tags: html, css

i want to add a red border to a drop down list like this:

```
   <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

i tried with `style="border:1px solid red"` but it doesn't work. 
also i tried adding the select drop down list into a span with red border but it doesn't look nice.

Comment: What exactly do you want? If I have `select {border: 1px solid red;}` in my CSS I get a red border around the select box. Is it that you want a red border around the whole drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

This should form a red border to the drop down

```
<select style="border: 1px solid red">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it forms a border in the select box,what exactly are you looking for describe...if you want custom dropdown then you have to design using div and style it.

Comment: sorry.also in Internet Explorer i need that border. in chrome appears but not in IE8